# Creating a float64 Variable in tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, tensorflow

I am trying to do a logistic regression and my training dataset is derived from a a numpy float64 array. My code looks like,

```
import tensorflow as tf
graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
    examples =tf.constant(mat6)  # mat6 is a numpy float64 array
    t_labels = tf.constant(labels) # labels is an a numpy float64 array
    W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([115713, 2]))
    b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2]))
    logits = tf.matmul(examples, W)+b
```

This throws an exception

```
TypeError: Input 'b' of 'MatMul' Op has type float32 that does not match type float64 of argument 'a'.
```

This probably because W and b are float32 and not float64. Is there a way to convert W and b OR create it as a float64

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To make this work, you should define the `W` and `b` variables with `tf.float64` initial values. The [`tf.truncated_normal()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/constant_op.html#truncated_normal) and [`tf.zeros()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/constant_op.html#zeros) ops each take an optional `dtype` argument that can be set to `tf.float64` as follows:

```
    W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([115713, 2], dtype=tf.float64))
    b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2], dtype=tf.float64))
```

Comment: Another work around I found was to use tf.cast.. like so, W = tf.cast(tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([115713, 2])), tf.float64)

Comment: Consider going the other way and downcasting to float32. That should run much faster on GPU etc and you rarely need the extra precision for NN in most cases.